# web MVC - how to report back model's processing result

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Everyone understands mvc as he wills, but sometimes I do not, at all.
Currently the majority of my controllers look like this:

```
<?php
$input = $_REQUEST['field']
$model = new Model();
$status = $model->launchSpaceShuttle($input);

switch($status)
{
    case Model::STATUS_LAUNCHED:
        header('Location: Mars');
        break;

    case Model::STATUS_INVALID_INPUT:
        echo "Please press the big red button correctly";
        break;

    case Model::STATUS_PILOT_IN_HANGOVER:
        ...
        ...
    case etc.
}
```

This leads to the obvious question:
Is this how it's supposed to be? Model's returning status codes and controllers deciding how to display and what?
Because this very much conflicts with the theory about simple, short controllers that act as a really thin wrapper between the input device and the model.

*bonus case*: what about ajax requests if I'm too lazy to create a view ;

Comment: Why is this tagged ASP-NET MVC ?

Comment: I tried editing and removing it, but it must have been added back in. Should not be here.

Comment: Mistagged. And it wasn't re-added. See the log. (btw, is handled differently in .net) I assumed it to be the same mvc. The dollar got you confused ?

Comment: thin vs fat controller is completely a matter of preference and not a stead fast rule by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that's easy. Just move the entire switch to a view file.
It's the view's responsibility to interact back with the user.

**Redirecting from inside the view is just as fine.**
Anyway in most frameworks the view file inherits the `$this` variable which represents the active controller.

Same regarding ajax requests.

Comment: This is just a suggestion. I'm not sure that's the ultimately correct answer.

Comment: you have not written the code in Codeigniter format for one , second , in my opinion what you are doing is correct , ie letting the controller decide what action to take , after fetching status from the model , (y)

Comment: I omitted the `public w/e action`. The question is, whether the controller should decide about the post action or shouldn't, because in the class `mvc` pattern it server only as input handler.